# how to execute an npm package cmd on a subdirectory via powershell?

Tags: angular, powershell, npm, angular-cli

How can I execute an npm package cmd on a subdirectory via PowerShell?  I have an ng2 app integrated into a parent .NET MVC app. So the ng2 directory is a subdirectory of the parent root directory like this: MySite/ng2

I need to update an existing PowerShell script (build.ps1) which exists in the parent app root directory to call the "ng build --prod" cmd of the Angular CLI within the context of the MySite/ng2 subdirectory. What approach should I use to do this?

Comment: Does ng.exe have a path parameter of some kind?

Answer (score 0):

This approach will work:

```
cd mySubdir
#exec special cmd against mySubdir
cd ..
```